# iOS 10 : Receive Remote Notification in background

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, unusernotificationcenter, remote-notifications

I am implementing FCM push Notification.

I get notification when App is in foreground.
But I do not get Notification in the background.

In server end I have set content-available => true

On iOS 10, should I implement any other method or where do I get background notification?

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresentNotification notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void)
{
    print("userNotificationCenter : Forground")

    completionHandler([.Alert,.Sound,.Badge])
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceiveNotificationResponse response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: () -> Void)
{
    //Code Todo After User presess notification
}
```

PHP Server Payload Code :

```
$payloadFeild = array(
        'registration_ids' => $gotoFcmUidVar,
        'data' => array('MsgKey'=>json_encode($fcmMsgVar)),
        'content_available' => true,
        'priority' => 'high'
    );
```

Comment: Have you added `Background mode - Notifications` to your app's entitlements ?

Comment: Yes I have enable Background mode - Remote Notifications

Comment: Have you followed the steps in [FCM's guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/receive) ?

Comment: Yes, I followed. So I get foreground notifications and their guide talks only about foreground notification

Comment: There's a similar post in their repo: [FCM did not received push notification when background mode for ios10](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-ios/issues/194)

Comment: 1. Can you show **exactly** what the payload looks like? You can find the correct format from [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CreatingtheNotificationPayload.html). FYI you can't add badge/alert/sound for the notification in your **iOS** code.You should configure it from server! 2. You don't need to write `UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert`. Just write `.alert`

Comment: Additionally the 2 methods you wrote are **same**. Only that the first one is for Swift 2.x. and the second one belongs to Swift3. If you want to get a callback then to implement `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:)`. For more see my other answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44705892/5175709)

Comment: Sorry, Updated the code now

Comment: 1. Do you just want to see the notification coming?! Or you want to get callback? If you want to get callback and do something in the backgorund silently then implement: `application(_:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHa‌​ndler:` ? 2. If you want **see** the notification then you should see the link I sent before. Your payload should be similar to `{
    "aps" : {
        "alert" : "You got your emails.",
        "badge" : 9,
        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
    },
    "item1" : "bar",
    "item2" : 42
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got this fixed after struggle 2 months by adding 2 things :
This is missing in all documentation and is to help all whom I wish not to struggle like me

|*| Try 1) : For Ios 10 background notification, Add following deligate method in AppDeligate :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings)
{
    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
}
```

> Got this solution from : https://codentrick.com/firebase-cloud-messaging-ios/

---

|*| Try 2) : If using Firebase : Set a value in **"info.plist"**
Property List View :

```
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled -> NO
```

Source Code View :

```
<key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
<false/>
```

I Had only mentioned FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnable. So be careful of spelling too.

Comment: same issue i am facing now, but notification does not works when app is background