# How to know FCM notification come in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

Hello friends I am using FCM first time in IOS, I have a condition. when I get notification I have to insert some data, But unable to do. Without sliding I am not able to trigger any function.So can anyone advice me how to resolve this issue.
Only this function is calling after sliding

```
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{

if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive){
    //application was in foreground
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
} else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateInactive){
    //application was in background
    NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
}else if (application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateBackground){
     NSLog(@"%@",userInfo);
}


}
```

Can anyone help me,Thanks in advance.

Comment: is this function getting called at all? You can easily verify that with a breakpoint. Also in your payload, are you setting `content-available` to `1`?

Comment: @Honey Thanks to reply, Yes I used content-available = true on server side,I also used breakpoint and after sliding notification only this method triggers. But I need a method that trigger when notification comes to Iphone

Comment: This method gets triggered the moment your phone **receives** notification. So I don't understand what the problem is. If you want to do something **upon tapping** then you have to use: [`userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:
`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unusernotificationcenterdelegate/1649501-usernotificationcenter?language=objc). For more see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44425744/alternative-to-usernotificationcenterdelegates-willpresent-when-app-is-in-backg/44705892#44705892)

Comment: try this :-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{ }

Comment: @Honey Thanks but this method triggers when I slide the notification message. If I close/cancel it ,this method have not called.

Comment: @Kuldeep that function [is deprecated in iOS 10](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application?language=objc) and shouldn't be used.

Comment: @Udaikumar 'this' means which function. Be specific

Comment: @Kuldeep Thanks for replay bro, this function is not working. It is not triggering in any condition.

Comment: @Honey -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{ this

Comment: did you get notifications?

Comment: @Kuldeep yes I get notification but with -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler{ this method

Comment: than you just have to get data from userInfo and based on that you just need to insert your data.

Comment: @Kuldeep Yes I am getting data but while sliding or opening the notification. But I want a method to trigger when notification comes in Iphone like android a method called is "onMessageReceived"

Answer (score 0):

You need to add [`UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/unnotificationcategoryoptions/unnotificationcategoryoptioncustomdismissaction?language=objc) to the category you register with your notificationCenter **&** add that category to the content of your notification (because the 'registered category of notificationCenter' should match with the 'category of the notification's content it receives').

For more see this [moment](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/707/?time=1609) from the Introduction to Notifications WWDC 2016

EDIT:
**What are categories?**

Notifications by themselves are just messages which contain a body and nothing more. If you want to add any form of action then you need to do 2 things:

- add that action to the content of the notification
- add that action to your usernotificationCenter.

categories help you add/group these actions and add accordingly. Sometimes a single notification my need to be dismissed, replied, liked <-- 3 different actions, grouped into 1 category.

To register a category with the unusernotificationCenter do:

```
UNNotificationCategory* generalCategory = [UNNotificationCategory
     categoryWithIdentifier:@"GENERAL"
     actions:@[]
     intentIdentifiers:@[]
     options:UNNotificationCategoryOptionCustomDismissAction];

// Register the notification categories.
UNUserNotificationCenter* center = [UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter];
[center setNotificationCategories:[NSSet setWithObjects:generalCategory, nil]];
```

<sub>copied from: [Registering the Notification Categories for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW26)</sub>

And then from your server also add the same category name ie from the above example add `generalCategory` to your `category` key. For more see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/PayloadKeyReference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH17-SW1).

And then from your `userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCo‌​mpletionHandler:` you can do:

`switch response.actionIdentifier` and handle the *tapping* using the case of `UNNotificationDismissActionIdentifier`

Comment: I made an edit. Make sure you watch the WWDC video entirely. After that go through this [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-the-usernotifications-framework--cms-27250). Everything will be more straightforward after this.

Comment: @Udaikumar did you go through the WWDC and tutorial? Did the answer help?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am working on this. Bro I think these function help in APNs, but I am trying to using FCM that is google notification. Yet I am trying to do, your post is really very informative but unable to understand how to implement it. I am not able to add action in notification centre,how could i used it

Comment: can you say one thing, for triggering ,I have to use this code to server side? For triggering method can i use notification centre code on serverside?

Comment: And if you dont know how to trigger a notification then ask a new question. But beforeyou fo that make sure you search the available answers/questions.